# how to seperate numbers using : by groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

consider a number 12345678.

I need output as 12:34:56:78 by using groovy script.

I have tried using .split()

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Comment: Also what happens when your number contains an odd number of digits?

Comment: How are you defining where one number ends and another begins?  Are they always 2 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code which does what you describe:

```
def number = "12345678"
def result = number.collect().collate(2).collect{it.join('')}.join(':')
```

the number is defined as String - if yours is a number, just turn it into a String with `.toString()`

`number.collect()` turn the string into a list

`.collate(2)` creates sublists of size 2

`.collect{it.join('')}` joins the elements of the sublists

`.join(':')` joins all sublists with the `:` character

maybe it is not exactly what you need, but it should give you a good starting point. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using regex.

```
t = "123456789"  // yes, i've extended to 9 to show what happens
(t =~ /(?<=(\G.{2}))/).collect{ it[1] }.join(":")
==> 12:34:56:78
```

As has been noted in comments on your question, you have to decide what to do when there aren't an even number of chars, as you can see in my example, it drops the last char because it groups by dual characters.